# What is the difference between SVN update to head vs synchronize with repository?

Tags: eclipse, svn

When I right click on my project in eclipse I see two options synchronize with repository and update to head. I am not getting what is the difference among them?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The difference is following:

**Update to HEAD** will do [`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.update).

In other words it will update your working copy to the last revision from the repository.

**Synchronize with Repository** is something similar to [`svn status -u`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine), but even more.

It will open a Synchronize tab (or perspective) that displays overview of your local (outgoing) modifications versus repository (incoming) modifications.

In this tab or perspective, you can review and synchronize (commit / update) individual files, see differences between your working copy files and incoming files from repository, browse commits history, resolve conflicts.

In general, I highly recommend you to check out the [SVN Handbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html). 
At least first two chapters.

Comment: @Parker, 'Update to version' does it mean 'Revert Modifications' in Subversion in 'Net Beans IDE' ?

Comment: @Woody, Sorry, I have no experience with Net Beans IDE. I suggest you to open a new question.